# Entity framework map column only if it exists

Tags: sql, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I am trying to find a way to only populate a property of my entity class, if the column exists in the query?

When I execute a query using DbSet.SqlQuery and returning the column (which is an alias) populated, everything is fine. But when using the built in functionality such as All(), Find(), ToArray() etc, it expects that column to be in the dataset.

Is there a way (without having to write all of the supporting queries manually) to mark a property in my entity class, as optional.

It is currently marked as a nullable DateTime but the framework still complains it does not exist when using the built in functionality.

Any suggestions would be great!

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

No, because they have to build the SQL query. It doesn't matter if a column is nullable or not, what matters is that when they build the query, if that column does not exist, then the database will likely throw an error complaining that the column does not exist.

The only way around it is to not map it, or to query the schema when mapping and conditionally map the property (though I wouldn't recommend that).

Comment: Urgh, thanks Darren. I recall there being a virtual method that populates the entity class from the DbSet. If I recall correctly, I might be able to override this and set the "notmapped" property if the value exists in the row? thanks again.